# Is it possible to overload deconstructors in C# 7.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

In C# 7.0 I can declare the following deconstructors for my class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public void Deconstructor(out string firstName, out string lastName, out string company)
    {
        firstName = FirstName;
        lastName = LastName;
        company = "Nop-Templates";
    }

    public void Deconstructor(out string firstName, out string lastName)
    {
        firstName = FirstName;
        lastName = LastName;
    }
}
```

I suppose the idea of using our variables in the desconstructor instead of directly returning a tuple is so that you can have different overloads of the deconstructor. However, I do not seem to be able to deconstruct the object to three variables. I can only deconstruct it to two variables.

For example, this does not compile:

```
(string firstName, string lastName, string company) = customer;
```

And I get this error:

"Cannot deconstruct a tuple of '2' elements into '3' variables."

But this does and works:

```
(string firstName, string lastName) = customer;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can overload the `Deconstruct` method with different number of parameters and different types.

Comment: And when you say "this does not compile ... but this does", what is the difference? The two pieces of code look 100% identical to me.

Comment: It would help if this was real code - unless you problem is just that you've used the wrong name for your `Deconstruct` methods?

Comment: Also, you may tell the error thrown when code does not compile

Comment: Thanks guys! I corrected the code and added the compiler error.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], I'm not convinced we're seeing the correct code here.

Comment: @Pikoh The deconstruct method is completely separate from the constructor, not the same thing at all.

Comment: The code compiles if you name the methods `Deconstruct` instead of `Deconstructor`, and the error message you get if you keep them with the wrong name is a different one from the one you mention about a tuple. Again, please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You have called your methods, `Deconstructor`, rather than `Deconstruct`. Also, you can't redeclare `firstName` and `lastName` in the two tuples. Make those change, and the following lines of code all compile just fine:

```
var customer = new Customer("a", "b");
(string firstName1, string lastName1, string company) = customer;
(string firstName2, string lastName2) = customer;
```

Comment: And thus by extension, since he says he has a compiler error, there has to be more things wrong.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, his claim that `(string firstName, string lastName) = customer;` compiles makes no sense; it doesn't compile as his code currently stands. If the methods are changed to `Deconstruct` though, then it compiles.

Comment: You are both right. First I have mistakenly called the methods Deconstructor. But also the customer which I am trying to deconstruct comes from an external service (just a demo) and this services actually, returns a tuple. And I thought it was returning a Customer object and was trying to deconstruct it.